# tensor with only certain elements trainable or other custom schemes

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to set certain values of a tensor as not-trainable? For example, if I want a weight-matrix to be an upper-triangular matrix, some parts of the matrix are just not trainable.

Also, what if I, for example, want every value on the diagonal to be the same value, but a trainable one?

EDIT: I am not interested in untrainable tensors, or variables, but whether it's possible to set certain elements as trainable!

Comment: A simple solution is to write your matrix as a sum of two matrix, one is diagonal and the other contains 0 on the diagonal and then set the first to be trainable and the other not.

Comment: interesting idea, seems rather complicated, but it should work!

Comment: I think this won't work, because your trainable diagonal will just take gradient steps into being no longer diagonal.